# How do create a Rails Email User Mailer View that auto-resizes to fit on iOS mail?

Tags: css, ios, html, email

I notice other emails from services like FB and Foursq have emails that auto resize in my iPhone. What is the trick to making this happen? Any layouts available to use? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the MailChimp templates: http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/